# Headmark on first chapter page with scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage, scrreprt

How can I make KOMA-Script package `scrlayer-scrpage` add a header to every page, even the pages where a new chapter starts?

I got this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, ngerman, oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\newpage
\section{2nd Section}
\end{document}
```

Which adds a header to every page except the pages where a chapter begins.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first page of an chapter is formated with style `plain.scrheadings` so you need to define it.

One possibility is to use something like `\chead*{\leftmark}`. The asterix marks that also style `plain.scrheadings` has to be changed too.

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, ngerman, oneside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[%
  headsepline,
  plainheadsepline, % <=================================================
  automark
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles % <==============================================
\chead*{\leftmark} % <==================================================
\ihead*{\pagemark} % <==================================================

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\newpage
\section{2nd Section}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting first page]

Comment: Why not using `\chapterpagestyle`?